# sorting a strange array of objects in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, object

I'm editing someone else's code here:

```
foreach($list as $items) {
   // displays items names and images etc
}
```

and within the foreach() loop I can see the name using:

```
echo $items[0]->name
```

and looking at the contents of $items it looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 7 [name] => Bench Scales // ..etc..
```

But I can't seem to reference name outside the loop

```
$list[0]->name // doesn't work
```

So I'm kinda stuck at this point when trying to sort by name, Yep I've looked up usort() and am happy with the concept of sorting by name, but am unable to sort this array of objects? by name. Any help most welcome

Above the foreach() loop I tried something like this, but no luck:

```
function cmp($a,$b) { return strcmp($a->name, $b->name); }
usort($list,"cmp");
```

Comment: `$list[0]->name` is not the same as `$items[0]->name`. Why do you think they are interchangeable?

Comment: Btw, in loop you're using `$items[0]->name` and in comparison function - `$a->name`. What makes you thinking that `[0]` is an optional element?

Comment: Leemo's answer's below helped me reference it, bit silly really my brain was turned off today :/ - Code included in my comment below his answer. Thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example:

```
$list[0]->name; // doesn't work
```

**Shouldnt work** Remember that when you're inside a foreach, you're one level nested when you access the iterable such as `$item`. Therefore

Assuming that the array has numeric indicies and that The 0th value in `$list` is an object this would work:

```
$list[0][0]->name;
```

Comment: You're making an assumption that `$list` has numeric based and continuous indexes

Comment: Exactly... I should clarify in answer body

Comment: Ah I was a bit brain dead, your right, $list[0][0]->name and $list[x][0]->name will work, so when I run $list thru a sorting bit of code: the changes are this: function cmp($a,$b) { return strcmp($a[0]->name, $b[0]->name); } usort($list,"cmp");    Thankyou so much!

Answer (score 0):

To me (and I'm kind of tired right now) this doesn't look like a sort issue. $list is a collection (obviously) and when you run it through the foreach loop, each iteration is giving you a single object array to work with, which is why your first example works. $list is an array of arrays, so you need one more level of "access" to get what you want.